# Friedel-Crafts's alkylation of Toluene

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, electrophilic-substitution

In the Friedel-Craft's alkylation of Toluene with $\ce{CH3Cl}$ in the presence of $\ce{AlCl3}$, the major product was meta - substituted. My teacher gave it to me as an exception. Is there any particular reason behind this reaction ?

Comment: I could hazard a guess at an answer, but would rather not, as there are some things which really need to be clarified first. (1) Is this "major product" you're referring to obtained under *thermodynamic* control, or *kinetic* control? (2) Does this "major product" result from multiple substitutions, or only one? (3) Spellings: it's "Friedel-Crafts", "toluene", and chlorine is "Cl", not "cl".

Comment: Appreciate     Appreciate

Comment: Funny how, i don't see these questions when i look them up.

Comment: Really i dont think meta xylene is the major product here. atleast thats what my teacher taught me

Comment: @VAMSIKRISHNACHILAKAMARRI, I think you should also consider the points in my comment, minus the spelling one, of course.

Comment: @orthocresol Oh yeah the thermodynamically major and the kinetically major differ. However on general questions like this i think it normally means kinetically. As it is not specified I dont think thermodynamics is the case. However your comment could be the reason........